# Keeping track of number of samples in each bin usings pandas pd.resample

Tags: pandas

When using `pandas` is it possible to keep track of the number of samples within each resampled bin?

For example given the sample data:

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00    1
2000-01-01 00:01:00    2
2000-01-01 00:06:00    3
```

With resampling on the `time_scale` 5min, there will be 2 samples used to create the first bar, and 1 sample used to create the second bar, I would like to keep track of this.

The result I am looking for would be

```
index                  val  count
2000-01-01 00:00:00    1.5  2
2000-01-01 00:05:00    3.0  1
```

Comment: Can you post some specifics about your problem?  What is the problem and goal?

Comment: `df.resample('5T').count()`?

Comment: @ayhan that will just tell you the number of rows in the full sample. Let me update my example to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume this is your DataFrame:

```
df
Out: 
                     C1
2000-01-01 00:00:00   1
2000-01-01 00:01:00   2
2000-01-01 00:06:00   3
```

You can apply multiple functions to groups using [`.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once):

```
df.resample('5T')['C1'].agg({'val': 'mean', 'count': 'count'})
Out: 
                     count  val
2000-01-01 00:00:00      2  1.5
2000-01-01 00:05:00      1  3.0
```

`count` counts the number of observations in each group, and `val` is their means.

Comment: What if there are more columns i.e. if you have `df.resample(time_frame='5T', how='OHLC')`

Comment: ohlc is a special combination of first, last, min and max so you can do: `df.resample('5T')['C1'].agg(['first', 'max', 'min', 'last', 'count'])` or concat the results: `pd.concat([df.resample('5T').ohlc(), df.resample('5T')['C1'].agg('count')], axis=1)`